# Setting a session variable on page view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, page-lifecycle

I am writing a multi-branded application (i.e it shows a different look for different users depending on where they are directed from).

The end-users come to the site using a query string to set the client id, for example

```
mysite?clientID={GUID}
```

What I am trying to do is set perform the following checks

```
If Session["ClientID"] is null or empty
    if querystring has ClientID 
        Set Session[ClientID] to QueryString[ClientID]
    else if the user has their clientID set in the db
        Set Session[ClientID] to DB Value 
    else 
        Use default ClientID
End
```

The code to check the various items I can easily work out, what I'm stumped on right now is where to "shove" this code so its checked on each page load.  More specifically if I should use a application lifecycle event hook, which one would suit this best so I have access to the Membership object, the QueryString and the Session object, before any pages are rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the request life cycle (among others):

- Application_BeginRequest.
- Application_AuthenticateRequest.
- Application_AuthorizeRequest.
- Application_PostAuthorizeRequest.
- Application_ResolveRequestCache.
- Application_AcquireRequestState.
- Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute.
- Your page event handler is executed
- Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute.
- Application_ReleaseRequestState.
- Application_UpdateRequestCache.
- Application_EndRequest.

For a detailed specification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx

So I think the event best fits your needs is:

**Application_PostAuthorizeRequest**

MSDN description

> Occurs when the user for the current request has been authorized.

source:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postauthorizerequest.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Application_BeginRequest` event in global.asax, or you could put it in the code-behind of your MasterPage if you have one, or in the code-behind of a BasePage file if your pages inherit from one.

Answer (score 1):

Your global.asax (in home directory) is the best place.

```
protected internal void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // your code
}
```

read more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw.aspx

Comment: I don't believe BeginRequest has access to the User values yet, so I wouldn't be able to access the Membership.GetUser() command would I?

Comment: New government and interrupting internet in Greece. Take Jupaol's proposal (same as my plan for update).